# How to read display name from kerberos service ticket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, kerberos

After application service gets a Kerberos service ticket from the client over HTTP header. How we can read `cname` (aka UPN) from the ticket.

I'm using ruby this ruby gem https://github.com/zenchild/gssapi reading service ticket from header (Authorization).
And If I try to read display_name (cname) right after request come it's working fine.

Result: `example@local.com`

But, When I do test with actual service token as a string and keytab file I'm getting error that no display name in memory.

`*** GSSAPI::GssApiError Exception: gss_display_name did not return GSS_S_COMPLETE but 131072:  An invalid name was supplied unknown mech-code 0 for mech unknown`

```rb
host = "example.org"
service = "HTTP/example.org@example.org"
token = "Negotiate YIIGUAYGKwYBBQUCoIIGRDCCBkCgMDAuBgkqhk....."
keytab = "/home/ubuntu/keytab.keytab"

gss = GSSAPI::Simple.new(host, service, keytab)
credResult = gss.acquire_credentials
puts 'Read cred form keytab: ' + "#{credResult}"

contextResult = gss.accept_context(Base64.strict_decode64(token))
puts 'Hello, ' + "#{gss.display_name}"
```

From RFC 4178 docs (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120.html#section-5.5.1) `cname` (UPN) should be in kerberos ticket's authenticator and able to decrypt and parse it with the app secret key.

I suspect that the GSSAPI C library doing something over TCP protocol storing `cname` (UPN) somewhere in memory and memory address as stored global variable, not able to read it.

Or I'm misunderstanding some part of GSSAPI implementation.

Here are my questions

1. Is it possible to get `cname` from service token as string?
2. How peoples do offline test with Kerberos authentication for application service?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, sorry. Display Name is not a field in a kerberos ticket. What you get is the principal name, and optionally if coming from Active Directory you can get their Full Name. Not all GSS implementations understand the extra data included from AD though.

Comment: @Steve,  Thanks for your reply.
If I want always to have a principal name from AD I should do implement extra logic with GSS library something like that?

Comment: @Steve, Hi again.
I thought that application token contains "authenticator" and inside of "authenticator" has "cname" (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4120.html#section-5.5.1)
Is not it UPN from AD or LDAP.

Comment: Yes, the CName is the user's UPN. It would not be their full name though, just the username.

Comment: @Steve thanks for your reply. Then I think I able to get at least UPN from Kerberos ticket right. But still if I when use encoded SPNEGO token string for this library (It should work same as C library) still not able to get the display name (aka UPN), And I'm not popular C and there is no good docs how to use it. 
So, I stuck in here.
Anyway, thanks to clean up my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I spend a lot of time to understand how the Kerberos protocol works. And let me leave it in here what I could know.

The [GSSAPI ruby gem](http://%20https://github.com/zenchild/gssapi) is a wrapper gem of GSAAPI libraries **Simple version** which is only for strict authenticate Kerberos token against Keytab file.

Actually, GSSAPI another specification which contains the Kerberos ticket. Sound like Russian nested doll.

1. rfc1508
2. rfc4178
3. rfc4120

And **GSSAPI Simple** implementation itself quite strict like you can get UPN from Kerberos ticket once GSSAPI token passes all validations. Otherwise, you will get just errors.

So, Ruby gem passes values into GSSAPI::Simple C library and getting results. This is why you cannot get UPN from the expired or invalid Kerberos ticket.

Ruby gem had small issue which throw very, very long error message when you get an error from C libraries because it's uses another gem which help wrap C code with Ruby code without native C code. Long error made me very confuse and it's required some time to get what is the actual issues.

Anyway, if you are interested this gem I would suggest to remove some memory clean up error like this: https://github.com/zenchild/gssapi/pull/29

Additionally, If you really need to get UPN from Kerberos ticket even ticket is expired or invalid. You need to parse Kerberos token with the RFC 4020 specification (KRB_AP_REQ).
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120.html#section-3.2

For that you can use [The MIT Kerberos library for Kerberos V5](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist). But this library very huge. Also uses lot of global memory address (Maybe it's security reason).

Or maybe you can use following some implementations.

[Java implementation](https://github.com/EleotleCram/jaaslounge-decoding/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jaaslounge/decoding)

[WIP status ruby implementation](https://github.com/Zogoo/ruby_keytab_parser)